# Can't run SSIS package as a SQL server agent job ( because of SAP GRIDVIEW element)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ssis, excel-interop, sap-gui

I made an SSIS package with a script task that scrapes SAP GUI for data and saves it. It uses the `sapfewse.ocx` reference.

The task runs perfectly locally but fails when running the package as a job or with dtexec. The error says that one of the SAP grid view elements could not be found. I cannot export from SAP without accessing this component so I do not know what to do.. Has anyone encountered something similar?

Comment: _Where_ are you running it? On a different server? Then you need to install those elements in there too. Note also that by default SSIS runs in Data Tools as a 32 bit process, and runs under SQL Agent as a 64 bit process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the project didn't run when I minimized the SAP window as it was running. I added a bunch of delays between my gridview commands and it started to work.

Answer (score 0):

As with prior answer from Nick, you need the SAP GUI dependencies installed. If by luck, you dont need all of them, You can try copying (sapfewse.ocx and any dependencies for that ocx) to the same path as SSIS package on the server.